# How do I set up default cell magics for every ipython notebook cell?

Tags: python, r, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have an iPython notebook that is completely made up of R cells. At the start of every cell, I have defined my R cell magic as follows:

```
%%R
```

However, is there a way to have just set that as a default for the entire notebook, so I don't have to type it into every cell?

Comment: If you are planning to write `R` in every single cell, maybe using a python kernel is not the right choice for you.
There is a project named [`IRKernel`](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel) that gives you a native kernel in `R`. Then every cell is evaluated by an `R` interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IRKernel](http://irkernel.github.io/) is an R kernel for ipython/jupyter as suggested by @cel. There are [lots](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPython-kernels-for-other-languages) of other kernels that you can use.