# Choose SQL as default cell magics for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I'm writing a Jupyter notebook for a database course; most cells will contain SQL code, for which I use the [IPython SQL magic](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql). Currently I have to prepend each cell with `%%sql`. Is there a way to avoid typing `%%sql` before each cell, by making it the default?

I found a related question at
[How do I set up default cell magics for every ipython notebook cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490801/how-do-i-set-up-default-cell-magics-for-every-ipython-notebook-cell). However, I couldn't find a SQL kernel for Jupyter.

Comment: I would love to find an answer to this too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Jupyter docs](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frontend_config.html) tell you how you can edit the CodeMirror settings. CodeMirror has an option called `value` that determines the default value of a CodeMirror cell ([doc link](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#config)).

So, in `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json` paste in the following code:

```
{
    "CodeCell": {
        "cm_config": {
            "value": "%%sql"
        }
    }
}
```

and now every new cell will have `%%sql` in it. Obviously this solution applies to any cell magic or indeed any default value you may want your code cells to have.