# How to enable timing magics for every cell in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The `%%time` and `%%timeit` magics enable timing of a single cell in a Jupyter or iPython notebook.

Is there similar functionality to turn timing on and off for every cell in a Jupyter notebook?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490801/how-do-i-set-up-default-cell-magics-for-every-ipython-notebook-cell) is related but does not have an answer to the more general question posed of enabling a given magic automatically in every cell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415452/choose-sql-as-default-cell-magics-for-jupyter-notebook may be relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hacky way to do this is via a custom.js file (usually placed in `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`)

The example of how to create buttons for the toolbar is located [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/4.0.x/notebook/static/custom/custom.js) and it's what I based this answer off of. It merely adds the string form of the magics you want to all cells when pressing the enable button, and the disable button uses `str.replace` to "turn" it off.

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
], function(Jupyter, events) {
    events.on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
        Jupyter.toolbar.add_buttons_group([
            {
                'label'   : 'enable timing for all cells',
                'icon'    : 'fa-clock-o', // select your icon from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons
                'callback': function () {
                    var cells = Jupyter.notebook.get_cells();
                    cells.forEach(function(cell) {
                        var prev_text = cell.get_text();
                        if(prev_text.indexOf('%%time\n%%timeit\n') === -1) {
                            var text  = '%%time\n%%timeit\n' + prev_text;
                            cell.set_text(text);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            {
                'label'   : 'disable timing for all cells',
                'icon'    : 'fa-stop-circle-o', // select your icon from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons
                'callback': function () {
                    var cells = Jupyter.notebook.get_cells();
                    cells.forEach(function(cell) {
                        var prev_text = cell.get_text();
                        var text  = prev_text.replace('%%time\n%%timeit\n','');
                        cell.set_text(text);
                    });
                }
            }
            // add more button here if needed.
        ]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, but I failed to mention that I am running on a corporate Jupyter server and I'm not sure I have access to `custom.js` to test it.

Comment: Finally got a chance to test this on a different system. As written, the answer doesn't make much sense -- having both `%%time` and `%%timeit` in every cell is not useful. So everywhere your answer says `%%time\n%%timeit\n`, I replaced it with `%%time\n`. But the general approach works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the icon for `fa-clock-o` works but not `fa-stop-circle-o`. Jupyter core version 4.2.0.

Comment: @abeboparebop Were you able to test it on corporate jupyter server? (I am in the same position and would love to know if you were able to do it.)